# Tag friends in photo using graph api

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2

I want to tag user's friends into the photo which is uploaded by user from my application....anyone please help me in that...i will be very thank full....i m using codeigniter as a framework....
i already created an photo album in user's profile and uploaded that photo into that but now i want to tag his friends fetched from his friend list...

this is the code i used for creating the album and uploading the photo =>

```
$fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => '148056051963323',
            'secret' => '0cebf087b3084e5a772b6c31acb2736a'  
        );

        $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
        $this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
        $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'For more LoL images check out -> http://lolsharing.com/',
            'name'=> 'LoL Sharing'
        );
        $album_exist_check = $this->common_model->check_album($_SESSION['user_fb_id']);
        if($album_exist_check['album_id']==0)
        {
            $create_album = $this->facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
            $insert_ablum = $this->common_model->insert_ablum($_SESSION['user_fb_id'], $create_album['id']);

        }
        else
        {
            $create_album['id'] = $album_exist_check['album_id'];
        }
        $photo_details = array(
            'message'=> ''.$image_name['image_caption'].' for more LoL Images check out - http://lolsharing.com/'
        );
        $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath(''.FCPATH.'assets/joke_images/'.$image_name['image_name'].'');
        $upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
        if($upload_photo)
        {
            $this->common_model->user_point_counter($image_id);
            $this->common_model->user_self_point_counter();
            if($upload_photo)
            {
                //redirect(''.$_SESSION['return_url'].'');
                echo "<div class='button1'>Image Shared.</div>";
                echo '<div class="num_share">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; Total Shares <br />
                        <span>&nbsp; '.$image_name['shares'].'</span>
                        </div>';
            }
        }
```

please help me..thanks in advance

Comment: hey shashank can you please show me your model.I tried your code for uploading pic on facebook but its showing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to add tags.  The example I'm giving is using the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

See also the `tags` section of: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

1. request a token with the appropriate permissions (see above link for the permission you will need)
2. Enter in your photo ID and click Get
3. Add /tags to the graph url and click Get to see what tags already exist
4. Change Get To Post in the dropdown
5. Click Add a field, Name= to, Value= a friends id or your id
6. Click Add a field, Name = x, value = 45
7. Click Add a field, Name = y, value = 45
8. Click Submit
9. Change Post back to Get in the dropdown
10. Click Submit to see the new tag
11. Of course the person you're tagging in the photo might need to approve the tag if they have their security features set as such.

Comment: it doesn't work at all for me... :( something has changed ? Can you verify this solution is still working for you ?

Comment: Currently friend list can not be accessed . so, how to tag a friend without using friend id/how to get friend's id?